# Auto expand suggestion details in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode.

When trying to use autocomplete, I get that kind of collapsed box which is not very useful. It forces me to use my mouse.

How to get that "Auto import from ..." always expanded ?

[image: Preview]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the following command id:

```
toggleSuggestionDetails
```

Defaults to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> [windows], while the suggestion list is active: `suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus`

For brevity, the command is a toggle, so you only need to enable it once and the toggle state persists.

Alternatively, if you just want parameter hints you can search for the following command id:

```
editor.action.triggerParameterHints
```

Which defaults to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> [windows]

Answer (score 0):

I had a look to the keyboard shortcuts and I realized you can expand the details by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> another time.

Comment: Your answer provided no new information opposed to those already given

Comment: You're right, I've read your previous answer again and I didn't understand it well at first place. Sorry and thanks.