Show box preview (panel right) suggestions in VSCode
I don't know if it's an extension or a configuration, but before a right panel appeared next to each suggestion, but now it doesn't appear. I've searched for the topic in several places but I don't have the answer. How can I show the right panel with the suggestion preview?


What happens if you hit Ctrl+Space when that suggestion box is open?  Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62827760/836330

@Mark I'm not talking about the popup, that does appear, what doesn't appear is the preview, the second box on the right that shows a portion of the code

Yes, that is what I was referring to.  Ctrl+Space should open that when the main suggestion box is already open.

@Mark Oh my God, I had to press CONTROL + SPACE twice for it to appear, thank you very much, I didn't think this was the case.

The answer is: If the Preview box on the right does not appear, you must press CTRL + SPACE twice again for it to appear.
